# Origen de la frase "más heavy que el viento"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, españa, locuciones

Llevo usando esta frase desde que me la enseñaron el primer año de la universidad, y seguro que para entonces ya era antigua... pero ¿de dónde viene esta frase?

> *Eres más heavy que el viento*

Ya sé que en teoría *heavy* no es un vocablo español, pero desde luego se usa para el estilo musical y para los valores asociados.

EDIT

Es una frase que he escuchado en España. Lo de la universidad era para decir que la frase ya tiene añitos...contad con que fue a finales del siglo pasado. Y no, no es ni mucho menos exclusiva de ámbitos universitarios.

Por supuesto, antes de preguntar busqué en Google (1320 resultados) y se encuentra de todo:

- [Han usado la frase para presentar al cantante de Obús en el programa de Ana Rosa (una presentadora de TV en España)](https://www.telecinco.es/elprogramadeanarosa/2012/febrero/01-02-2012/ana-rosa-fan-obus_4_1358235032.html)
- [Foto con ese nombre, de 2008](https://www.comunidadumbria.com/comunidad/galerias-de-fotos/foto/2606)
- [Playlist de spotify con ese título](https://open.spotify.com/user/1169737901/playlist/44ehJpC9Pnswo5Jhw976xI)
- [El cine del Metal: 10 películas más ‘heavies’ que el viento](http://cinemania.elmundo.es/noticias/el-cine-del-metal-10-peliculas-mas-heavies-que-el-viento/)
- [Grupo de Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/295510649382/about/)
- [Un foro en el que se tenía que rellenar "soy más heavy que..."](http://heavyrock.foroespana.com/t1246-mas-heavy-que)

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Date cuenta de que en muchas ocasiones las expresiones son muy locales, llegando incluso a estar asociadas no a una población, sino a un contexto determinado como puede ser el caso de tu universidad. ¿Podrías decirnos exactamente en qué ámbitos la has escuchado? Ya sabemos que en tu universidad, aunque no sabemos exactamente cuál es. ¿También en tu ciudad a gente que no es de la universidad? ¿En tu provincia? ¿En tu país? Cuantos más datos nos des y más específico seas, mejor podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Y por cierto, que la palabra _heavy_ sea un préstamo del inglés [no quiere decir que no esté en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K41sF2E)...

Comment: Nunca he escuchado esa frase. Deberías especificar en que país o región la usan. Además deberías especificar que significa o en que contextos se usa.

Comment: @Charlie ni se me ocurrió buscar en el DLE. ¡Qué cosas! Ahora me surge la duda de cuál es la pronunciación normativa en castellano (porque no acompaña pronunciación), si será "como se lee" o "en inglés"

Comment: @malarres pues teniendo en cuenta que he visto escrito "jebi" en muchos sitios... :-)

Comment: @malarres Si te fijas, la palabra *heavy* aparece en cursiva en el DLE. Eso significa que es un extranjerismo crudo; es decir, que se usa en castellano tal cual, sin adaptar, por lo que no sigue las reglas de pronuncación del idioma. En estos casos, la RAE (o la ASALE) no se mete en la forma de pronunciar la palabra.

Answer (score 2):

No estoy seguro de si lo que quieres saber es cómo se originó la frase, cuándo se originó, o quién la originó. Solo puedo especular con lo primero, y es que creo que sencillamente la frase se originó por el concepto de "mover las melenas al viento" del mundo *jebi*.

Lo dice el propio artículo de las películas más 'heavies' que el viento:

> Te presentamos una antología para mover tus melenas al viento.

También recuerdo este concepto en alguna que otra canción de Gigatrón:

> *Rebeldes de cuero
>
>   vibran sin cesar,
>
>   melenas al viento,
>
>   tachas y metal.*
>
> Gigatrón, "Rebeldes de cuero", ¿1998?

Obviamente [Gigatrón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigatron) es un grupo de rock humorístico que parodia a los clásicos grupos de *heavy metal*, pero aún así los tópicos existen por algo y el de las "melenas al viento" lo es.

Lo del origen de las melenas asociadas al *heavy metal* parece tema de debate, algunos dicen que viene heredado de la cultura de los 60 en la que tener el pelo largo (al menos en el mundo masculino) era señal de querer romper con lo establecido. De ahí pasó a las bandas de rock (busca fotos de Black Sabbath de los 70), y de ahí al *heavy*. También hay quien asocia las melenas *heavy* con la mitología vikinga (otro tópico del *heavy*). Sea como sea, el *heavy* y las melenas van  de la mano, y ¿qué mejor que el viento para mover y ondear esa melena y poder tener ese aspecto *heavy* de película?

Sobre su fecha de origen, el problema es que no encuentro textos registrados ni en el CREA ni el el CORPES XXI que contengan la expresión. El más antiguo que encuentro en Google [es de 2002](http://www.thesentinel.es/reportaje_weekendwarriors.htm):

> Y por fin aparece, ¡y qué tía más maja, de verdad! ¡Y encima es más heavy que el viento!

Comment: [Definición de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigatron): "Gigatron es una banda española de rock humorístico que editó varios discos [...]. Se trata de una banda humorística que parodia el heavy metal de los años 1980 y 1990, caricaturizando las actitudes, estética y elementos típicos del género."

Comment: Gracias @Charlie. Antes de 1998 se tenía que decir porque me la enseñaron como por esa fecha, y digo yo que no sería de nuevo cuño justo en ese momento. Pero de veras que gracias por el esfuerzo. Por cierto, lo de "melenas al viento" me parece un poco cogido por los pelos (perdón pero si no hago la broma reviento) porque en inglés no hay una frase similar (ellos usan heavy as lead) ...en fin, será cuestión de irles a preguntar a los heavies de la Gran Vía ;)

Comment: @malarres es cierto que la historia del origen es una suposición mía. Pero no entiendo que creas que está cogido por los pelos (te acepto la broma) solo porque en inglés no haya una expresión similar. Entiendo que cada idioma genera sus propias expresiones. En inglés no hay traducciones literales de frases como "de tomo y lomo" u otras, cada idioma puede coger su inspiración de sitios diferentes. Pero vamos, que sí, que lo mío es solo suponer. Si preguntas a los heavies y te dan una explicación, no dudes en publicar tu propia respuesta, es una práctica muy respetada.